# Is it possible to pass in more than one generically typed parameter to a method?

Tags: c#, .net, generics, .net-3.5

I currently have this method header:

```
public virtual void SetupGrid<T>() where T : class, new()
{

}
```

I want to pass in another anonymous class, I guess something like this:

```
public virtual void SetupGrid<T><T2>() where T,T2 : class, new()
{

}
```

How can I do this?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

These are called generics. Here's how you use several of them:

```
public virtual void SetupGrid<T, T2>() 
    where T : class, new()
    where T2 : class, new()
```

Start from [this](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms379564(VS.80).aspx) MSDN page for an introduction and much more info.

Comment: Fastest compiler in the West :)

Answer (score 2):

You're talking about generic type arguments, not anonymous class types

Yes this is possible:

```
public virtual void SetupGrid<T,T2>() 
   where T : class, new()
   where T2: class, new()
{

}
```

Answer (score 1):

like this:

```
        public virtual void SetupGrid<T, T2>() where T : class, new() where T2 : class, new() {
```